# Structure my Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to structure my dictionary in Python. The input list looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Test A",
        "date": "28.12.17",
        "name": "Person 1"
    },
    {
        "title": "Test B",
        "date": "28.12.17",
        "name": "Person 2"
    },
    {
        "title": "Test C",
        "date": "28.12.17",
        "name": "Person 1"
    },
    {
        "title": "Test D",
        "date": "28.12.17",
        "name": "Person 2"
    },
    {
        "title": "Test E",
        "date": "29.12.17",
        "name": "Person 1"
    },
    {
        "title": "Test F",
        "date": "29.12.17",
        "name": "Person 2"
    },
    {
        "title": "Test G",
        "date": "29.12.17",
        "name": "Person 1"
    },
    {
        "title": "Test H",
        "date": "29.12.17",
        "name": "Person 2"
    }
]
```

Now I want to generate an output which looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "entries": [
            {
                "entries": [
                    {
                        "title": "Test A",
                        "date": "28.12.17",
                        "name": "Person 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Test B",
                        "date": "28.12.17",
                        "name": "Person 1"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "Person 1"
            },
            {
                "entries": [
                    {
                        "title": "Test C",
                        "date": "28.12.17",
                        "name": "Person 2"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Test D",
                        "date": "28.12.17",
                        "name": "Person 2"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "Person 2"
            }
        ],
        "date": "28.12.17"
    },
    {
        "entries": [
            {
                "entries": [
                    {
                        "title": "Test E",
                        "date": "29.12.17",
                        "name": "Person 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Test E",
                        "date": "29.12.17",
                        "name": "Person 1"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "Person 1"
            },
            {
                "entries": [
                    {
                        "title": "Test F",
                        "date": "29.12.17",
                        "name": "Person 2"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Test G",
                        "date": "29.12.17",
                        "name": "Person 2"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "Person 2"
            }
        ],
        "date": "29.12.17"
    }
]
```

How can I do this with Python? Thank you for your answer in advance.

Comment: Please paste your data/code samples in the body of your question, and please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Suppose data holds your input
out = []
for date in set([d['date'] for d in data]):
    d_by_date = {"date": date, "entries":[]}
    for person in set([d['name'] for d in data]):
        p_entries = {}
        p_list = []
        for d in data:
            if d["name"] == person and d["date"] == date:
                p_list.append(d)
        p_entries["entries"] = p_list
        p_entries["name"] = person
        d_by_date["entries"].append(p_entries)
    out.append(d_by_date)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You helped me very much!